# xls String to Array in JavaScript

Tags: arrays, string, xls, csv

```
String.prototype.splitCSV = function(sep) {
  for (var foo = this.split(sep = sep || ","), x = foo.length - 1, tl; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (foo[x].replace(/"\s+$/, '"').charAt(foo[x].length - 1) == '"') {
      if ((tl = foo[x].replace(/^\s+"/, '"')).length > 1 && tl.charAt(0) == '"') {
        foo[x] = foo[x].replace(/^\s*"|"\s*$/g, '').replace(/""/g, '"');
      } else if (x) {
        foo.splice(x - 1, 2, [foo[x - 1], foo[x]].join(sep));
      } else foo = foo.shift().split(sep).concat(foo);
    } else foo[x].replace(/""/g, '"');
  } return foo;
};
```

this code is convert csv string to array. my question is that how to convert xls and tsv string to array?

Comment: you need to append the javascript tag to this, also put it in proper code segments

Comment: @user3178816 The link does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql)'s CSV parser, which can convert CSV and TSV strings to array:

- [CSV and TSV parsers code](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/version-0.0.34/src/84from.js) (sorry, I cannot put all code her because of size)

Or you can use Alasql to load data from CSV, TSV, XLS, or XLSX files directly to JavaScript:

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM XLSX("mydata.xlsx")',[], function(res){ 
    // do something
});

alasql('SELECT * FROM TSV("mydata.tsv", {headers:true})',[], function(res){ 
    // do something
});
```